# Typescript always types the result of reduce function as any if the array is any[]

Tags: typescript

I have a reduce function that takes an array of `any`s and should produce an array of some type. However typescript is always assigning `any[]` to the result of the reduce function. No matter if I type the initial value with the proper type or if I type the callback return type with the proper value, I always get an array of any. Is this correct or a bug on TS?

Here you have a basic example:

```
type Employee = { x: boolean }
type Item = {}
type Results =  {data: any[]} 

const doStuff = (results: Results, employees: Employee[]) => {
  const nonExistingEmployees: string[] = [];
  const pensionsInputs = results.data?.reduce((acc: Item[], item: Item) => {
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return { pensionsInputs, nonExistingEmployees };
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmANgexBaBeKBvKAPALigCNllEIBDAOygF8AoUSKASWAjii20eegBKEAM4BXRMGHcoOACaVglIjRABtALp0oDBgGNk1YcCizkAZWCiAZlekAKAE4jxkokLEThAGiickqdGEieH80CA0ASm4APhwGGX1DY2oDGDwASyN06gBzEJQwoKgjB2ycjWkNAG54qESjKEhDdINhVmowUUlpJw9JADp5RQB+fqdZUV0IOztKXV0idk4NH3SOOEX1qIxY7FqZJ0sHWjndGpk6H0jzqEPRY5xGiGbW9s7JHxTqNMzgMvyAiJ6DU6DUgA)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would declare the array as any and then assign the value afterwards, it kinda defies the purpose of typed language. But to answer your question, you should move as Item[] outside the brackets. Reason being is that you need to cast the type to the whole result. Right now you are saying that the first element of the array is of type Item[]

Comment: I'm typing it as any to reproduce the issue. The results are coming from a library (which is interfering with the end user) and they are typed as any, which is something expected for values you have to validate because they come from the user. What do you mean to move the `as item` outside the brackets? Where exactly? `const x as Item[]` ? That is just casting, and I want TS to actually check the types are correct apart from the initial Any.

Comment: You would do like this: const x = results.data.reduce((acc, item) => { return acc.concat({x: item.x}) },[]) as Item[]; This will cast the whole type to the array. The empty array given as second argument of the reduce function is the initial value to start the reduce (basically so you won't start with null). You were casting the type to the initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the accumulator, not the initial value:

```
const x = results.data.reduce((acc: Item[], item) => { return acc.concat({x: item.x}) }, [])
```

This will provide type checking for anything you do with `acc` inside the callback function, although `item` will still be `any` unless you also provide a new type for that.

**Edit:**

This is not something I was aware of but it turns out that providing a new type for both accumulator and current values will revert the function override which happens when providing a type for just the accumulator.

So another way to type this in your new code sample might be:

```
const pensionsInputs = (results.data as Item[]).reduce((acc: Item[], item) => {
  return acc;
}, []);
```

`item` is now automatially typed as `Item`. You could just as well do what the other commenter suggested and forget typing the individual elements of the reduce call, instead just asserting that it is an `Item[]` after the fact, the only difference being you don't get type checking inside the callback function.

Or else just assert that `results` is what you think it is as soon as you get it, before trying to do anything else with it - this is probably the cleanest solution without doing any of your own validation. And you probably should be doing your own validation instead of any of this if you're not 100% sure about what the result will be at run time.

Comment: That is something I tried already. On the simplified example it works, but on the real code it still shows the x (the result) as an array of any. Do you know any common mistake that could lead to this?

Comment: I just updated the question to include a example which is closer to my real code. In this case, no matter what you annotate, the result is always an array of `any`

Comment: @Danielo515 see the edit.